# How to get a hold of one of RecyclerView adapter's items by its parameter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` and an Adapter fills it with `CardView`s

Every card gets filled by an object's data. The objects are contained in a list.

How do I get one of the card (so that I can change its visibility) after the cards have been inflated and displayed to the user, by using one of the object's parameters?

I could set the `CardView` tag to be the parameter and then somehow retrieve it by its tag?

Comment: Your CardViews would be a part of the Holders which would be reused by binding to various items in you Adapter list. So are you interested in getting a reference to the reusable Holder (UI part) or the item binding to the Holder (Data Part)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You data class:

```
class MyObject {
    String name;
}
```

Get a view by object parameter:

```
MyObject myObject = null;
String lookingName = "Ozgur";

for(MyObject tmp: myList) {
    if(tmp.name.equals(lookingName)) {
        myObject = tmp;
        break;
    }
}

if(myObject == null) {
    return;
}

int position = myList.indexOf(myObject);
View v = recyclerView.getLayoutManager().findViewByPosition(position);
```